# Java generics "reverse relationship" (and JPA)

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I have these 2 classes:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Compound {


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="compound",
        targetEntity=Containable.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)      
    private Set<Containable> containables = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity 
public abstract class Containable {     

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Compound compound;
}
```

What I want to achieve in a type-safe manner is that a specific implementation of Compound only accepts a specific implementation of Containable and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

I already had the solution from asenovm, just wanted to double-check it is actually the correct one.

My follow-up question is, if I have `class Compound<T extends Containable>` and `class Containable<T extends Compound>` Containable and Compound are raw types or do I get that wrong? Because in `class Compound<T extends Containable>` T is actually a Containable and not anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
@Entity
public abstract class Compound<T extends Containable> {


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="compound",
        targetEntity=Containable.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)      
    private Set<T> containables = new HashSet<T>();

}

@Entity 
public abstract class Containable<T extends Compound> {     

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private T compound;
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea too but it does not work with JPA (Hibernate) and Table per class. -> foreign key constraint violation when inserting a containable for Compound A, it says "No record in table fro compound B with id xyz".

Comment: And with `ChemicalCompound<T extends Containable>` one method of Compound, `compound.getCompositions()` now seems to return a List instead a List<Composition>. (Incompatible types compile error). makes no sense to me...